# WPF/XAML: Is there a way to use x:static with a function?

Tags: wpf, xaml

This is my XAML:

```
ItemsSource="{x:Static app:HealthCheckSystemCategoryLookup.All}
```

Is there a way to make HealthCheckSystemCategoryLookup.All a function instead of a property?

Answer (score 3):

No, `x:Static` can only handle enum members, properties, and fields.  You can use [`ObjectDataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider.aspx) if you want to bind to the result of a method call.  You would do something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider
        x:Key="Data"
        ObjectType="app:HealthCheckSystemCategoryLookup"
        MethodName="All"/>
</Window.Resources>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Data}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just bind to a property which calls the method in its Getter.

```
public IEnumberable<object> Data
{
  get
  {
    return All();
  }
}
```

Comment: What I'm binding to doesn't have property semantics. It can potentially fail or takes a long time to read. Repeated reads do not necessarily give the same result.

Comment: Then maybe you need to extend this data provider, or put a wrapper around it to handle the errors, cache results, run it in a separate thread etc.